# Isolating values from a listbox line

Tags: c#, database, string, ms-access, listbox

I have got a line in a lisbox that i need so i can print out my receipt for the end of my 12 grade project im doing.
Example of my line :`"cha1  Adidas Stan Smith White  1  2"` (its padded).
Now what i want to do is isolate like cha1, Adidas stan Smith White,1,2 to add to my Microsoft Access Database, i somehow managed to do it with substring but i screwed up my code and now i cant do it , can somebody help me please ?

My code ,that used to work , looks like this :

```
 foreach (string item in lstpreview.Items)
            {
            //create the string to print on the reciept
            string nomeproduto = item;

            float quantidade = float.Parse(item.Substring(item.Length -5, 5));
            float precounitario = float.Parse(item.Substring(item.Length - 5, 5));
            string totalproduto = item.Substring(item.Length - 6, 6);

            txt1.Text = Convert.ToString(quantidade);
            txt2.Text = Convert.ToString(precounitario);
            //MessageBox.Show(item.Substring(item.Length - 5, 5) + "PROD TOTAL: " + totalproduto);

            //float totalprice = 0.00f;





        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You say that the line is padded, but do not give any details. If you know that the first field is always the first 4 characters of the line, you can isolate it with [string.Substring](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aka44szs%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
string field1 = line.Substring(0, 4);
```

and similarly for the other fields.

P.S. Please edit your post and remove the swear word.

**Edit after parsing code added**

I don't understand your comment, what is "your negative value"? Run the code in the debugger and find which line causes the error. Please post the exact error message.

Is there a reason for converting the substring to a float and then back to a string? I can imagine that you might want to validate that the field is numeric, but then you would be better to use `TryParse`.

Your second comment is helpful. The last 5 characters of the line are not all numeric, that's the problem.

Comment: I edited out ( sorry for the swear word) and i added the code that i use wich is very much like yours but when i try to put 0 in my negative value it gives me an error message.

Comment: The line is exactloy this "ADIDAS STAN SMITH FLAT WHITE/GREEN1                             1" and the values it keeps returning me is 1

Comment: Negative value:(item.Length -5, 5). What you are saying makes perfect sense , the thing is i shoul'd have gone for a string but when i look at the code i didnt even realize. And the last comment you had was a moment of eureka , thank you so much , i will try to implement your line of thinking to my code , you where  very helpfull , thank you !

Comment: No error message appears now , thanks , im trying to make the program work :)

Comment: One thing , the name of the product is variable as so is the other text, so for example that one had 50 or so characters but another of the names has 75 characters, can you understan where im going? i think to Say exactly where is the word is a bit difficult without knowing how long it is.

Comment: @Ricardo Please mark my answer as accepted if it helped you. Your next point may be seen as a new, separate question. I would take characters, one at a time, from the end of your string; see if it is a number or a space and stop when you get to the product name. There may be a solution using regular expressions, there's plenty of help for that online. It would be much easier if you could have a separator or some rules to make the parsing easier.

Answer (score 0):

Done it with this snippet of code together with a for each loop.

```
string[] caracteresnastring = item.Split(new char[] { ',' }.ToArray());
            string code = caracteresnastring[0];
            string name = caracteresnastring[1];
            string price = caracteresnastring[2];
            string quantity = caracteresnastring[3];
```